# AssetImage is not displaying image in flutter app

Tags: dart, flutter

image not displaying in flutter app.
But I got some errors in debug console.

```
I/FlutterActivityDelegate(22603): onResume setting current activity to this
I/FlutterActivityDelegate(22603): onResume setting current activity to this
I/Timeline(22603): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3eb59326 time:39937973
I/flutter (22603): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SERVICES ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (22603): The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter (22603): Unable to load asset: assets/images/logo.png
I/flutter (22603): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (22603): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
I/flutter (22603): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (22603): #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:383:44)
I/flutter (22603): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (22603): #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:368:14)
I/flutter (22603): #3      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:265:86)
I/flutter (22603): #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:82:22)
I/flutter (22603): #5      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:265:63)
I/flutter (22603): (elided 8 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter (22603): Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/logo.png")
I/flutter (22603): Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#19ce7(), name: "assets/images/logo.png",
I/flutter (22603): scale: 1.0)
I/flutter (22603): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
D/ViewRootImpl(22603): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
D/ViewRootImpl(22603): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
```

My Pubspec.yaml file

assets:
     - assets/images/logo.png

login.dart code

new Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png", width: 60.0,
              height: 24.0,
              fit: BoxFit.cover)

**directory structure**

[image]

**pubspec.yaml file**
[image]

Comment: also take a screenshot of your pubspec.yaml file

Answer (score 22, accepted):

i mentioned images files in wrong way. i put space between  '-' and image name instead of tab.

assets:

```
- assets/images/logo.png
```

Don't put spaces between the character instead of tab in pubspec.yaml file

Answer (score 16):

There may be two issues:

**1.)** Either you pubspec.yaml file is not having proper indention. Attaching snippet for reference.

```
flutter:  
  uses-material-design: true   
  assets:   
    - assets/
```

`- assets/` will consider all the images in the directory.

**2.)** If you are using .jpg image then please change it to .jpeg wherever you are calling it.

Attaching the snippet for you reference

```
class _UserLoginState extends State<UserLogin> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image(image: AssetImage("assets/christmas.jpeg"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My issue was incorrect indentation. As a newbie to Flutter I just hit backspace to remove #, which makes keyword 'assets' sent to beginning of the line.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure the folder you are referring in Image.asset contains the file.

For example:

```
Image.asset(
"./assets/images/loading.gif",
height: 125.0,
width: 125.0,
)
```

The folder should be:

```
C:\your_app_folder\assets\images
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
```

Run flutter clean
to clean the intermediate files and refresh.

Answer (score 7):

`Hot Reload` was the issue in my case. I simply restarted the Android studio and re-run the app, it all worked!.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I assume you copied your files inside `assets/images/` folder right?
Also you need to reference your images into the `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
  flutter:

  ...

    assets:
      - assets/images/logo.png
```

Comment: i also added pubspec.yaml

Comment: Could you put the code that you are using to display the image? and also put the pubspec.yaml in your question .

Comment: @syamlal , where is located your file logo.png ? could you take a screenshot of your tree directory of the project?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue after adding a new image to the asset folder.  I was doing "Hot Reload", **I destroyed the app from the background, re-run the app** and the problem got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your image folder is in project folder.

Answer (score 1):

There are several opportunities to make the mistake, higher chance that it's in the  `pubspec.yaml` declaration.

- Most of the time it's better to specify the directory of your assets. This way you'll edit `pubspec.yaml` less frequently.
- The asset directory/item is not declared properly (e.g. wrong indent)
- If your IDE is Android Studio and you edited the `pubspec`, hitting the Run button won't cut it. Execute `flutter run` in the Terminal to run the app.
- If you can't type in the Terminal, flutter may already be running. Press `ctrl` + `c` to terminate the process then run. No need to restart your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Refer  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/AssetImage-class.html

Add assets images in pubspec.yaml file and in the asset mention the path from **images** and it works fine.

```
 new AssetImage("images/logo.png")
```

For example

```
CircleAvatar(
  radius: 80,
  backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/logo.png'),
 ),
```

Comment: I appreciate your kindness towards action on other correct answers. we have given solution to the problem after checking in our environment. Please go through the link https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/AssetImage-class.html and confirm using above code, user can load an image using the above code (AssetImage)

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced

```
Image.asset("assets\images\_Lightweight.jpeg"),
```

To

```
Image.asset("assets/images/_Lightweight.jpeg"),
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem was indentation of assets section. I wrote it at the beginning of the line, whereas it should be indented with a Tab after flutter: section.

Robie

Answer (score 0):

Your pubspec.yaml is not intended properly

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - images/
```

Check if it's intended this way.

Answer (score -1):

These changings will definately work.

```
AssetImage('mypicture.jpg')
```

Above is my code, I have not used "assets" folder name with my image file name and it works perfect.

and these are my assets in 'pubspec.yaml' file.

````
assets:
    - assets/cat.png
    - assets/mypicture.jpg```
````

Comment: There is no need for whole names directory names with a trailing slash will do it fine
- assets/

Comment: But if you want to add selected pictures in the assets then you have to write the name of file also.

Answer (score -2):

1. Flutter doesn't support jpg files.
2. Try the complete path of the file with '/'(forward slash).

Answer (score -3):

I was facing the same issue and did everything mentioned but the problem was I was using a route that was initializing another file first instead of my asset. you can also check  this if the problem persists