# Flutter image is not showing

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-image, flutter-assetimage

I want to show some local image and display it on the screen like this:

```
 Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/addFood.png'))
```

But I cannot see the image on the screen and I am getting no error at all.

### **Here is what I have done:**

In my `pubspec.yaml` I have added my image folder like this:

```
  assets:
    - lib/assets/images/
```

The image named "addFood" is inside `images` folder as you can see here:

[image]

I want to display a simple text with image under it, I can see the text on the screen and I am doing it like this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (favoriteMeals.isEmpty)

    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Text('no favorites',style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,),
      Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/addFood.png'))
    ]);

    else{
     ......
     ......
     ......
   }
```

**All I can see is the text without the image:**

[image]

### solutions that did not help in my case:

[AssetImage is not not displaying image in flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033603/assetimage-is-not-not-displaying-image-in-flutter-app)

[Adding assets and images](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)

[mage Not Appearing when Using "new Image.asset" inside a Column](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8673)

How can I fix it and make sure that the image will be displayed on the screen?

Comment: Do you really want to put your assets in `lib`? It adds unnecessary complexity to do that so I would recommend to move it up to the root unless there is a good reason to do that.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore . I don't have any preference regarding where to put my assets folder. what do you mean by  unnecessary complexity?  could you elaborate?

Comment: Oh sorry it seems that's only for assets from other packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the full path for an asset when accessing it within the code. Nothing is implied when accessing the assets. Your actual path is `lib/assets/images/`, but you only do `assets/images/`. Change your code to include this:

```dart
Image(image: AssetImage('lib/assets/images/addFood.png'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
flutter:
   assets:
     - assets/images/
```

Remove lib from pubspec.yaml path. And to get image in code use,

```
Image.asset('assets/images/lake.jpg')
```

Comment: This would not work, check Christopher @Moore answer

Comment: Why? I am not getting it

Answer (score 0):

Update `pubspec.yaml` file like this

```
   assets:
     - directory/subdirectory/
```