# AssetImage not updating on iOS until hot reload

Tags: flutter

I have a problem that, when trying to show an AssetImage, it will not show when the app opens. It does show, however, after performing a hot reload.

The problem only appears on iOS, and was tested on both a physical device and the simulator.

Flutter doctor gives no problems.

Here's my `pubspec.yaml`:

```
flutter:      
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

In images I have `appIcon.png` that shows, and `1.png` that does not show. `appIcon.png` is inside my main, while `1.png` is called from a StatelessWidget that calls a StatefulWidget containing the image.

I'm trying to show the image here:

```
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage("assets/images/1.png"),
      colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
        Colors.black.withOpacity(saturation),
        BlendMode.dstIn
      )
    ),
  ),
  ...
),
```

I don't know what else to include for debugging purposes, or where to look for solutions.
I have tried indentation problems in the pubspec.yaml as proposed here: [AssetImage is not not displaying image in flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033603/assetimage-is-not-not-displaying-image-in-flutter-app)
But with no luck.

Comment: Post the code where you try to show the image.

Comment: does this help?

Comment: what is the value of ```saturation```?

Comment: 0.85. But the image appears after hot reloading

Comment: are you doing some ```async``` stuff before displaying that particular widget? where exactly are you returning it?